# What's the diffrence between these two bitcoin.conf format?

Tags: solo-mining, bitcoin.conf

```
server=1
listen=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=X
rpcpassword=Q
rpcallowip=localhost
rpcport=Y
```

And

```
server=1
rpcuser=X
rpcpassword=Q
rpcallowip=localhost
rpcport=Y
```

I am a litlle confused, can these two conf file accepts solomining? And what's the difference between them?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering the second part of your question:

`server=1` tells Bitcoin-Qt and bitcoind to accept JSON-RPC commands, so you can query it

`listen=1` is a bitcoin listening mode

`daemon=1` starts bitcoind in the background as a daemon

`rpcuser=X` and `rpcpassword=Q` is the user/password for rpc access

`rpcallowip=localhost` means you can access it through rpc only from your localhost IP machine, add external IP if you want to access it from outside

`rpcport=Y` is the rpc port to access it (localhost:Y), for bitcoind the default is `8332`

AFAIK the second config won't work for rpc, you haven't specified rpcuser, and you will see the bitcoind output in the console (not a daemon).

Comment: Thank you Tony, But about `listen=1` **is a bitcoin listening mode** litening to what? To the rpc call?

Comment: It means, that your node accepts an incoming connection and uploads old blocks to other peers (when they are in the initial block download phase and later when propagation happens). Listening to rpc calls is defined by server=1.